# Collinearity among explanatory variables

Tags: multicollinearity, fixed-effects-model

My correlation matrix is not showing very high correlations (less than 0.5), but still, when I am regressing panel fixed effects models, all my variables are omitted, and it shows it is due to collinearity among the variables. What is the way out of it?

Comment: This site must already have a number of closely related questions. Please search `multicollinearity`, `singularity`.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have mulitple observations per person and you add person fixed effects, than you control for everything that is constant within a person like sex and race. As a consequence you cannot add these variables to your model, as you already control for them.